# MSI install from network share is downloaded several times during install

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-installer

I have an MSI file which is executed by a bootstrapper .exe - both residing on a network share. The .msi file is about 350MB in size.

When the .msi file is launched I get the windows installer dialog box saying something like "please wait for the installation to begin..." and I can see in the task manager that it starts downloading a lot of data. But, instead of downloading around 350MB, the msi installation does not continue until it has downloaded about 1.7GB. After that, the installation continues but once again it halts for a long long time at the step of "updating component registration" and once again it starts downloading something until it reaches well over 2GB of received bytes according to task manager.

This problem makes the installation process not only very inefficient but painfully slow on an already painfully slow network connection to that network share.

I can't help but to think that it should be possible for the MSI to be fetched once (I am not sure that it is as I suspect that the MSI-file is fetched several times over, but that is the feeling of it).

The MSI file is built using WIX Toolset and does anyone know if there is some attribute I should set in that XML or something to make it behave differently? Or could the problem be of a completely differetn nature? Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: The usual approach is to pack up the installer into a single self-executing file, which unpacks the MSI and other content to local disk before starting the install.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks for your reply! I see...that would probably mean a lot of work (going from the current setup procedure). Perhaps it can also be done by letting the current bootstrapper-exe explicitly download the MSI file which is placed there in the same directory anyway right now...and then just execute the MSI from that local path...

Comment: Should have the same effect, yes.